# redirect after 20 minutes

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

I have a landing page and a 90% discount.
after 20 minutes,
I want the page to redirect to another page (with another discount)

The problems:

1. after 20 minutes and redirect - the user wouldn't be able to go back to the original offer.
2. if the user stay less than 20 minutes and close the page, the next time he comes it should continue to count when it stopped.

I built a small code for that but it doesn't do what I want (write the time left in a cookie every 10 seconds

any suggestions?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var TimeLeft = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)TwentyCookie\s*\=\s*
    ([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

    if (TimeLeft == null) 
    {
      TimeLeft  = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
    if (TimeLeft > 1199)
       {
        //window.location.href = "http://google.co.il";
       }
    }
    for (i = TimeLeft ; i < 1201; i=i+10) 
       {
           myVar = setTimeout(UpdateCookie, 10000);
       }
   //window.location.href = "http://google.co.il";  

   function UpdateCookie() {
        document.cookie = "TwentyCookie="+i + '"';
   };
        window.onload = UpdateCookie;

   </script>
```

Comment: Try changing the expiration on a cookie, cookies are deleted by default usually when the session ends, which is when they close the browser

Comment: thanks, will do so, 
but this code isn't work as I want...